# Word press Cart update issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a wordpress website on my local server which works perfectly. The shopping experience of adding items to the basket and checkout works as expected but when I transferred it to the live server, this stops working correctly (the Mini Cart doesn’t update, and items get deleted automatically).

Despite previous suspicions, there is no custom code involved – the only variable is the live server.

I wonder if you please advise on what might possibly be going on, and if you’ve seen something similar before – perhaps cache/refresh/something else??

The website is approaching the launch date, and this is the final mystery.

Steps to find the issue:
Basket(cart) with zero item should display mini cart with empty basket message
Add two or more item to the baske, you have to refresh the page to get updated and once you navigate away from that page, the icon stop working.

I have cleared the cahce, and searched all over internet but no solution.

Site: http://www.test2.hydro-x.co.uk/

Comment: what os for the server? did you develop on windows? have you checked your `error_log`? What does the network panel in the web inspector say?

Comment: Have you asked this question over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Thanks. The local server was on windows 10 OS.

Comment: @Simba I suppose it is the same platform int?

Comment: @JohnsonBanky it's a sister site to stackoverflow, but specifically aimed at wordpress devs.